# VB.net if block throwing an error

Tags: vb.net, null

My code block is below. As it turns out, rdrCurrentRate.GetString(12) is a null value, but the code block throws an error.  "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

My intention is to write "if rdrCurrentRate.GetString(12) is NOT NULL, then sCurrentRateType = rdrCurrentRate.GetString(12)"

What am I missing here?

```
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rdrCurrentRate.GetString(12)) Then
                    sCurrentRateType = rdrCurrentRate.GetString(12)
                End If
```

Comment: "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx) method instead:

```
If Not rdrCurrentRate.IsDBNull(12) Then
    sCurrentRateType = rdrCurrentRate.GetString(12)
End If
```

Null values are not represented by `null` in the data reader, but instead of a special [`DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) value. The `IsDBNull` method will check if the column represents such a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If IsDBNull(rdrCurrentRate.GetString(12))=false Then
                     sCurrentRateType = rdrCurrentRate.GetString(12)                 
End If
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Close, but the GetString() method has a return type of "string", which can never match DbNull

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about 2 possibilities

1- An exception is raised in the rdrCurrentRate.GetString

2- rdrCurrentRate.GetString returns a DBNull value, which is not the same as Nothing (or null)